# Can log4j be configured to use Joda Time's timezone database?

Tags: java, logging, timezone, log4j, jodatime

I am using log4j (with JDK 1.3) and it is logging times one hour behind the actual time. This is because log4j is using the JDK 1.3 timezone information for daylight saving, which is out of date.

Unfortunately upgrading the JDK to get the latest timezone info is not an option for me. However, after running a test I can see that JodaTime 1.6 **does** have the correct timezone information.

Is it possible for log4j to be configured to calculate its dates using JodaTime rather than the JDK and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own `Appender` (maybe as wrapper around existing appenders) and configure the loggers to use the new `Appender`. Per [Javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Appender.html):

"Implement this interface for your own strategies for outputting log statements."

The method `doAppend(...)` accepts a `LoggingEvent` which has a [long-timestamp](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html#getTimeStamp%28%29). This method yields the milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00,000Z (well, Log4J-documentation is somehow slappy). Your own `Appender` can then convert this timestamp to a JodaTime type like this way:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("..."); // specify zone for output
LoggingEvent loggingEvent = ...; // given as argument in Appender-method
DateTime dt = new DateTime(loggingEvent.getTimeStamp(), zone);
String formatted = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("...").print(dt); // specify your pattern
```